# Python: Object cannot access __bases__ attribute

Tags: python

An class instance should have access to the classes attributes.
`__bases__` as per my understand is a class attribute
If I have a class called `C1`, I can call `C1.__bases__`
but if I define an instance of `C1`, `obj1 = C1()`, `obj1.__bases__` does not work? I am surprised because using attribute notation, it should start a search in `C1`'s namespace and find `__bases__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard attribute lookup searches through an object's `__dict__` and those of its class and its class's ancestors.

A class's `__bases__` attribute isn't defined in its `__dict__`. `__bases__` is managed by a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) in `type.__dict__`, which handles the attribute lookup by retrieving the tuple from an internal field in the class's memory layout.

Since `__bases__` isn't in `C1.__dict__`, looking up `__bases__` on an instance of `C1` doesn't find it. You have to look it up on `C1` itself.

Comment: Checks out... `type.__dict__['__bases__'].__get__(C1, type) is C1.__bases__`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the magic `__` methods are handled specially.  Do `obj1.__class__.__bases__` if you need this.

Answer (score -1):

`__bases__` is a class attribute, use

```
c1.__class__.__bases__
```